# Deleting rows is not fast enough

Tags: excel, vba

I have over `60000` lines in excel I need to weed down by reading the F Column. I have a Functioning Macro but it is taking forever. I am deleting the rows if in Column `F` the Value is `0` or null. I think my code may be too wordy. I am pretty new at VBA. I found this code online and tried to make it my own. Any help is greatly appreciated. My code is listed below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F62000")
    With rng
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Item(i) = "" Then
                .Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                If .Item(i) = "0" Then
                  .Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Also instead of hardcoding `62000` you can find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920).

Comment: I apologise for replying and then closing this question as a duplicate. I didn't know it was a duplicate but later realized it. See my comment below @A.S.H's post below.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows in a loop is a very slow process.

Here is a much faster method. This identifies the range that needs to be deleted and then deletes them in the end in one go. Also you have lot of unnecessary code which I have removed. I have not tested the below code but I think it should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, delRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To 62000
            If .Range("F" & i).Value = "" Or .Range("F" & i).Value = "0" Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Range("F" & i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Range("F" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete
End Sub
```

**Note**: Another faster method would be to use `.Autofilter`

Comment: I tired the code you suggested but it is deleting the columns not the rows thanks

Comment: Deleting the columns? My code doesn't delete the columns or the rows... It deletes the cells in Column F.

Comment: I had made a mistake. Thanks. I had it working but now it is giving me an item mismatched error. Do you have any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: which line is it giving you the error?

Comment: The auto filter worked great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

To cope with the possibility of your column `F` having both numbers and text, you can use `Autofilter` in two phases: one to delete where blank, and one to delete where `0`:

```
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F62000")
    .AutoFilter 1, ""
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter

    .AutoFilter 1, 0
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
  End With
```

From experience this is the fastest method to delete rows by criteria. Notice, though, that using `Autofilter` needs the first row to be a header row. Insert a blank row if that's not the case.

Comment: I was planning to add an Autofilter example as well :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout Then I saved you some work. Coffee is on you :P

Comment: Oops I just realised that this question is a duplicate. Your recent edit `From experience this is the fastest method to delete rows by criteria` brought back some memory and when I searched for it, I realized that this question has been asked before. See my comment below Brettdj's post in that question ;)

Comment: Ah, I didn't benchmark to compare speed of union vs autofilter, only noticed that autofilter is always faster up to some reasonable size. But well, if you did then kudos. On the other hand I wonder how many individual chunks can a union hold... do you know of a limit for that? @SiddharthRout

Comment: I doubt 60k rows will make any dent to autofilter's speed. You comment was like a blast from the past :D

Comment: I have not extensively tested it but both union vs autofilter will become slower over huge amount of data. However they are much faster than looping.

Comment: Yeah, that's sure.

Comment: The auto filter worked great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after it.

You have two `For i =` in your code. One inside the other... 
Use only one:

```
For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If .Item(i) = "" Or .Item(i) = "0" Then
       .Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Where you mean before code? I keep putting it after button click but it keeps giving me error "Control Variable already in use"

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way